# hostname -i command shows MAC address, ethernet device name and IP address

Tags: linux, ip, network-interface

I have removed the connection using **nmcli conn delete** command and added the IP back with **nmcli conn add** command. After that my **hostname** -**i** command gives weird output (actual value is written as what it is)

```
hostname -i
MAC_Address%ethernet_interface_name  IP_Address
```

How to correct this to give only the IP address?

Comment: What's the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @KevinLemaire "**ifconfig**" and "**ip a s**" all show proper output.

Comment: By any chance, is the MAC address in fact an IPv6 address?